# The orthogonal family of $y=c(x-2)e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y=c(x-2)e^x$ is curves family.

Find the appropriate curve of the orthogonal family which passes in $(-2,2)$.

First of all, I'll find the orthogonal family of $y$.

$y'=ce^x+cxe^v-2ce^x\implies y'=ce^x+y$ is the differential equation of the curves family.

Then, the differential equation of the orthogonal family is
$y'=\frac{-1}{ce^x+y}.$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{ce^x+y} \implies (ce^x+y)dy=-dx $

Here I get stuck.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Thank you , How I supposed to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General advice: in any issue about a family of curves and its orthogonal family, you have to get rid of the parameter (here c) !

From:

$$y=c(x-2)e^x\tag{1}$$

$$y'=c(x-1)e^x\tag{2}$$

Dividing (1) by (2) allows to get rid of parameter $c$, giving:

$$\dfrac{y}{y'}=\dfrac{x-2}{x-1}=1 - \dfrac{1}{x-1}\tag{3}$$

Using transformation $y' \to -\frac{1}{y'}$, we get the differential equation of the orthogonal family:

$$-yy'=1 - \dfrac{1}{x-1}\tag{4}$$

which can be integrated in this way:

$$\tfrac12 y^2=-x + \ln(|1-x|)+k\tag{5}$$

I leave you the final computations (take care of the sign of the RHS in (5)).

Here is a Desmos representation for the cases corresponding to curves passing through $(-2,2)$.

[image]

Comment: I have added a graphical representation.

Comment: Thank you very much! appreciate!

Comment: Another question please, I need to put $(x,y)=(-2,2)$ but $ln(-2−1) =ln(-3)$ how is it possible ? $x-1$ must be non-negtive number ,no ?

Comment: Sorry, it is an error of mine: I should have written $\ln(|x-1|)$ with absolute values not $\ln(x-1)$. Sorry for inconvenience. I fix it. If you plug $x=-2$ in the (correct!) formula for $y$ you get $\ln(3)$.

Comment: Now the function and the curves are correct (I have taken the case of curves passing through $(-2,2)$).